# Packer and git clone private repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, packer

I am building an image with packer where I use git clone to get a private repository via ssh.

I set a public key on github (deploy key), and the private key inside of the instance running packer on path `.ssh/id_rsa`.

I also added the github public key to the `known_hosts` to avoid warnings.

Basically, I have a provisioner script that sets the `id_rsa` on the beginning and then I remove it right after running the git clone command:

```
sudo cp id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-keyscan github.com >> .ssh/known_hosts
...
git clone ....
sudo rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I don't have the private key hardcoded on the id_rsa file, I am using a github secret key.

Is this a good practice and the only way of doing it?

Comment: Alternatively you could use the `HTTPS` URI with in-process environment variables for authentication. Those would not be as susceptible to an interception, especially if you read them via the Packer Vault plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use more secure ssh forwarding instead of copying the private key into the machine but found that `git clone` doesn't work properly this way and relays on ~/.ssh/id_rsa key.

Thus your approach seems to be reasonable.